# getting the current line number using gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm looking for a gulp plugin, or some code that will output the current line number of the line in a file being processed.

the usage will be something like the following, assume inside of a JavaScript file I have the following:

```
WOI_.functions.logger("images","$$linein","woi.bookmarkletsave",returned_obj);
```

then the $$linein macro should be expanded with the number of the current line being processed.

so if that code above is found on line 421 of the input file it should output

```
WOI_.functions.logger("images","421","woi.bookmarkletsave",returned_obj);
```

Comment: you can do it without gulp... `new Error().lineNumber`, or just put it in a function and use it wherever you like

Comment: thanks, that's better than what I was thinking of.

Comment: actually, I realized that won't work since gulp is used to compile the scripts I want to be able to see what the line number was in the original uncompiled script.

Comment: this will provide line number on the fly, rather than static line number